# Batch processing of image

Tags: image-processing, .net-4.0

I have been assigned to write a windows application which will copy the images from source folder > and it's sub folder (there could be n number of sub folder which can have upto 50 Gb images). Each image size might vary from some kb to 20 MB. I need to resize and compress the picture.

I am clueless and wondering if that can be done without hitting the CPU to hard and on the other hand, little faster.

Is it possible ? Can you guide me the best way to implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image processing is always a CPU intensive task.  You could do little tricks like lowering the priority of the process that's preforming the image processes so it impacts your machine less, but there's very little tradeoff to be made.

As for how to do it,

- Write a script that looks for all the files in the current directory and sub-directories.  If you're not sure how, do a Google search.  You could do this is Perl, Python, PHP, C#, or even a BAT file.
- Call one of the 10,000,000 free or open-source programs to do image conversion.  The most widely used Linux program is ImageMagick and [there's a Windows version of it available too](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php).